# Meteor/cordova run android app on multiple devices

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am developing android app on cordova. Now I need to test my app in multiple devices which is connected to Machine. 
`adb devices` shows

```
List of devices attached 
015d3f1935041019    device
2a52344 device
```

but `meteor run android-devices --verbose` install single device alone and shows

`error: more than one device and emulator
- waiting for device -`

Is there a way to run app in multiple devices?